# how to build destination parameter in azcopy

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azcopy

Hi I am new to hdinsight I am trying to copy file from my pc to my cluster sotckoverflowanalysis with `azcopy`

Here is what I have tried:

`AzCopy C:\myfolder https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer /destkey:key abc.txt`

My questions are:

- what is myaccount.blob.core.windows.net?
- what is mycontainer? is it the cluster or the storage?
- how do I get the destkey?

Answer (score 3):

> what is myaccount.blob.core.windows.net?

In this, `myaccount` is the name of your storage account where your files will be stored. Azure storage is accessible via REST API and `myaccount.blob.core.windows.net` is the endpoint for accessing blob resources. FYI, other resource types supported by Azure storage are: Tables, Storage Queues and File Service.

> what is mycontainer? is it the cluster or the storage?

`mycontainer` is the name of the container in Azure blob storage. Conceptually, it is very similar to a folder/directory on your computer in the sense that like a folder on your computer, a container contains blobs (or files in simple words).

> how do I get the destkey?

Each storage account comes with 2 keys - Primary and Secondary either of which is required to access resources stored in your storage account. You need to specify either Primary of Secondary storage account key for `destkey` parameter. You can get this information from Azure Portal.

Comment: my storage name is myhdinsightstore   is this going to be my account? my cluster name is stackoverflowanalysis  is this equivaltne to  mycontainer? i found the key : sskk123   and saved in  key.txt;  I guess destination will be https://myhdinsightstore.blob.core.window.net/stackoverflowanalysis/destkey: key key.txt   right?